# ArcGIS crashes when trying category symbology?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, symbology, windows-10

I'm facing an issue with ArcGIS 10.3. When I try to use symbology type "category" the program crashes. It seems that is not a matter of data because I used the data before and nothing happened. The problem started yesterday after a windows 10 update so I consider something relate do this update (may 10).

I tried the complete uninstall and reinstall and didn't solve the problem.

I tried also save the MXD with another name in other location.

So my question is related to the possibility of a problem caused by an windows update.

Any ideas?

Comment: Send an error report to Esri and try to roll back the update http://www.howtogeek.com/206271/how-to-roll-back-or-uninstall-a-problematic-windows-update/ I don't think this should be closed, I think it's important for users to know that there's an issue with Windows 10 update... others with this problem please also send your error report, the more that highlight a problem the more likely it is to get fixed: *the squeaky wheel gets the grease*.

Comment: If you are using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop and using Windows 10 then I think you should upgrade to 10.3.1 ASAP because [Windows 10 support begins at ArcGIS 10.3.1](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/get-started/system-requirements/arcgis-desktop-system-requirements.htm).

Comment: I think I discovered the problem. Is a kind of conflict with AVG Protection. If you use AVG antivirus (AVG Protection 2016.71.797 in my case), try to uninstall it, reboot and try ArcMAP again.

Comment: @JulioRefosco I'll re-open this so that you can add that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I discovered the problem. Is a kind of conflict with AVG Protection. If you use AVG antivirus (AVG Protection 2016.71.797 in my case), try to uninstall it, reboot and try ArcMAP again. It worked for me.

Comment: thank god you figured this out. saved me from losing my mind using arcmap. How did you figure out that it was a conflict with AVG Protection?

Comment: @ziggy In fact I spent almost a week testing the problem and trying several ways to find it.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted ESRI support about this issue and they sent me this response:

I did some research about potential issues with AVG antivirus and found that there is a related bug already logged with our parent company Esri Inc.

For your reference, this number is BUG-000096502: ArcMap crashes when modifying symbology when certain antivirus software is installed. It looks like this is a fairly new issue and the log mentions that "With AVG Antivirus installed, ArcMap will crash when a user attempts to modify symbology using Layer Properties > Symbology > Categories > the next click ArcMap will crash with an error report being generated." This sounds like it matches the problem you were having fairly closely, except that they are modifying the symbology of a vector layer in the above example.

There is a workaround listed in the bug details, which is to Set ArcGIS for Desktop as an exception to the antivirus software. These steps work for AVG:https://support.avg.com/SupportArticleView?l=en_US&urlName=How-to-exclude-file-folder-or-website-from-AVG-scanning