# ArcMap Crashes with ArcGIS has encountered serious error when Accessing Classified Symbology

Tags: arcgis-desktop, error-999999

Whenever I select classified symbology for a raster layer ArcMap will crash/close and give the message/ prompt to send error report: "ArcGIS has encountered a serious error.."

The problem is not associated with the data itself as it happens for any raster.

I have uninstalled ArcGIS 10.3 and reinstalled ArcGIS 10.4 and reset my normal file and the error still happens. There doesn't seem to be any issues with the install and the issue is new. I had been using ArcGIS 10.3 for a while with no issues.

The only change on my computer I can think of is I updated my AMD Radeon Display driver recently. However I have tried disabling it and running ArcMap and the same error occurs.

Comment: I have the same damn problem. It also crashes on me when I use the dissolve tool but I get no error. I have tried uninstalling and installing but to no avail

Comment: Hi Ziggy, looking through some other posts on here I came across this one:http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193236/arcgis-crashes-when-trying-category-symbology?rq=1 One person suggested a conflict with AVG. I disabled AVG and that looks like it may have fixed my issues. If you use AVG try turning it off and see if the error still occurs. Or if you use another Antivirus program it could be causing the same issue.

Comment: @awvanwychen have you been using ArcGIS 10.3 and AVG together for some time?  If so it may be a new update to AVG that's causing the issue.  This issue has appeared a few times over the last couple of weeks so might be a new issue worth reporting to AVG (if they'll even listen)

Comment: I do have avg il give that a try!

Comment: @Midavalo Yes I had been using ArcGIS with AVG for the past year and ArcGIS 10.2.2 for about a year before that with no issues. I will report the problem to AVG and hopefully it will be resolved with a future update.

Comment: Same here, disabled AVG and it worked fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/85412)